Can one publication contribute to two separate grants?
I have a set of collaborators I have worked and published with in the past who have received a new, rather large multi-year grant to continue some inquiry areas. I am not funded through that grant.
Is it possible/common for me to pursue my own funding from a different agency, with an eye toward joining forces with them to conduct the actual research? (This of course assumes I can write my individual grant in such a way that the activities and research questions overlap with their existing award.)
Essentially, is it ethical to "double count" a single publication as contributing toward grants awarded from separate agencies?

IMHO this can't have a generic answer as this would be mainly determined by the specific conditions imposed by the specific grant sources and their expectations; I've been involved in grant calls that had entirely opposite treatment of such situations.

I would ordinarily think about it the other way around: grants contribute to publications.
If a publication includes work supported by more than one grant, then it's not only acceptable but also necessary to acknowledge all of those sources of funding when publishing the paper.
Of course yes, when you submit some sort of progress report or go back at the end of your grant cycle and ask for more money, you'll report your productivity on that grant which may include work also supported by other grants, but at least in my world I think funders tend to view collaborative work and synergy between multiple grants as an overall positive.
I would expect funding agencies to each have their own approach to the concept of "overlap" at the time of submission and it may differ for different types of opportunities: graduate student and post-doctoral fellowships would be a category that almost certainly are expected to have overlap with other grants held by the mentoring PIs, for example.
You'll need to demonstrate in some way that funding your grant submission will make some contribution to the mission of the funding agency. "I want to be paid for this project that's already happening" is not likely to contribute to that mission. "My colleagues are collecting these data and I'd like to use these funds to pay staff to do X Y Z additional analyses with these data" might be, as would "we're already doing this experiment, but we want to collect these additional measurements that require an additional machine and personnel".
I would highly recommend consulting with grants staff at your institution, and possibly also with the "program officer" or similar role at the funding agency.


Essentially, is it ethical to "double count" a single publication as contributing toward grants awarded from separate agencies?

If the research being reported on in the publication actually benefited from the support of both grants, then yes, you should report to each of the funding agencies that the paper is one of the work products resulting from that grant, and list both grants in the acknowledgements or funding sources section of the paper.
It would be problematic to count the publication as having benefited from funding from a grant if there wasn't any actual support from the grant that was used during the research. Did the grant pay for the labor of a PhD student, some equipment, travel, etc, that could be associated with the research that was performed? If not, it would be a stretch to count it as being done under the support of the grant.
It would also be unethical (and most probably illegal) to draw support from both grants simultaneously to pay yourself or someone else a salary for the same period of work. That is, if Grant A is paying your summer salary for the entire month of July 2025, then naturally you can't draw a salary from Grant B for the same period, even if the grant has funding that allows that.
Other than these issues, you are free to pursue funding from any combination of sources, including for projects that have some overlap or synergy with each other. Grant applications usually include a form where you report what other funding support you are getting or have applied for (in NSF applications this will appear under the heading "Current and Pending Support"), so funding agencies are aware that researchers can enjoy more than one source of support, and are generally fine with it. However, keep in mind that if the overlap between your proposed research and already-funded research is significant, the funding agency may decide it is not interested in funding the same research that already enjoys adequate levels of support from a different agency.
To summarize, there is no ethical issue as long as you fulfill your respective obligations to each of the funding agencies, are truthful in reporting which grant or grants supported which research activities, and don't attempt to mislead funding agencies about the support you receive from other agencies.
I also agree with what @BryanKrause wrote in his answer. Especially this part:

I would highly recommend consulting with grants staff at your institution, and possibly also with the "program officer" or similar role at the funding agency.


I work in experimental physics, and our publications usually result from international collaborations and have long author lists. Every author acknowledges several grants, so the list of grants in the acknowledgements can be very long. This is perfectly OK. It can well be that every author is paid from a different grant, and the measurements were performed at an external facility that is also independently funded through some grants.

The answer by Bryan covers the main ground, but I'd like to highlight that at least in my country (Czechia), there were funding calls that required exclusive dedication to the funding agency (here AZV ČR). I.e. if you received the funding, at least one of the papers you produced had to acknowledge AZV ČR and no other source of funds.
Although this is AFAIK somewhat rare and was softened in the more recent calls (currently no dedication to other projects form the same agency is required, but funding from other agencies is OK). Still it is important to check the specifics of both the already awarded grant as well as the funding you are planning to pursue - the grant department at your institution should be able to help you with that.
